# Signed vs unsigned comparsion

Tags: c

```
size_t a;
off_t b;
...
if(b<a) ...
```

As expected, compiler makes "signed vs unsigned comparsion" warning here, since off_t is signed and size_t is unsigned. Is there any way to do such comparsion, working correctly on any platform, without using intmax_t/uintmax_t and preprocessor conditional directives?

It should work regardless of what sizeof(size_t) and sizeof(off_t) equals. They may have any values, for example:

```
sizeof(size_t)=4, sizeof(off_t)=8   (regular modern 32bit unix)
sizeof(size_t)=4, sizeof(off_t)=4   (older system)
sizeof(size_t)=8, sizeof(off_t)=4   (some 64bit system with 32bit filesystem support)
```

If I just typecast one to another, data loss and incorrect result may occur.

EDIT To be clear: negative values of b is not a problem as the negative b is easily detectable (if(b<0)) and will always be less than ANY value of unsigned a. The problem is comparsion of positive values of two such types, and i don't know what type have larger width.

EDIT2 It is not duplicate with "comparing off_t and ssize_t with other types" because that question is about comparing signed types with various bitwidth and this is about signed vs unsigned types; and first answer in that question is also not answering to this, becase that answer is about two same-sized types, and here is two unknown-sized types;
also this question is not just about comparsion, it is also about avoiding warnings

Comment: How will data loss occur? The difference between the two is just the sign bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(b < 0 || (b <= SIZE_MAX && (size_t)b < a))
```

should work in all cases.

If `b` is negative, then obviously it's less than `a` because `a` can't be negative (because `size_t` is unsigned).

If `b` is greater than `SIZE_MAX`, then obviously it's greater than `a` because `a` can't be greater than `SIZE_MAX`.

Otherwise, they're both in the valid range for a `size_t`, so it suffices to compare them as `size_t`s.

Comment: upv, I was about to post exactly the same expression

Comment: as was said in (why?) deleted comment, it still generates signed/unsigned warning for b<=SIZE_MAX; it seems not a error now but i want to compile it with -Werror flag so i searchign a way to remove this warning at all

Comment: @immibis it seems the warning-less condition is    (b<0 || (!(b & ~((off_t)SIZE_MAX)) && (size_t)b<a))

Answer (score 0):

No.

The problem is that 'any values' includes negative ones, in which case you must apply special code to handle it, as the underlying machine does not.

If you know that your values are guaranteed non-negative, then simply cast them to the unsigned type matching the largest operand.